# How to get just first element in html fie By using jsoup in JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to get just first thing in html..
How to get just first one..?

this is part of HTML file and I used Jsoup in JAVA.

```
<div class="product-shelf-author contributors">by <a href="/s/%22Carol V. Aebersold%22? 
Ntk=P_key_Contributor_List&Ns=P_Sales_Rank&Ntx=mode+matchall">Carol V. Aebersold</a>, <a href="/s/%22 
Chanda A. Bell%22?Ntk=P_key_Contributor_List&Ns=P_Sales_Rank&Ntx=mode+matchall"> Chanda A. Bell</a> 
</div><div data-bv-show="inline_rating" data-bv-product-id="9780976990703" data-bv-seo="false"></div>
```

by [Carol V. Aebersold](/s/%22Carol%20V.%20Aebersold%22?Ntk=P_key_Contributor_List&Ns=P_Sales_Rank&Ntx=mode+matchall),  [Chanda A. Bell](/s/%22%20Chanda%20A.%20Bell%22?Ntk=P_key_Contributor_List&Ns=P_Sales_Rank&Ntx=mode+matchall)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Elements writer1 = doc.select("div.product-shelf-author");
Elements writer = writer1.select("a[href]");
```

if I use this cord in JAVA "Chanaa A.Belll" is aslo added in Elements writer...

but I just want to add just "Carol V.Aebersold" in "Element writer" :((

Answer (score 0):

Class `Elements` extends `ArrayList`, so you can get first element which index is 0.

```
Elements writer1 = doc.select("div.product-shelf-author");
Elements writer = writer1.select("a[href]");
Element firstElement = writer.get(0);
```